# Вывод данных с ардуино с термопары

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

Вопрос касательно вывода данных с термопары подключенной к плате ардуино. Она подключается к 3 цифровым портам на ардуино для вывода данных с нее в режиме реального времени и постройки графика (также в реальном времени). Но никак не получается вывести данные, выдает ошибку `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

```
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pyfirmata
from time import sleep
import tkinter
import serial

def onStartButtonPress():
    while True:
        if flag.get():
            sleep(1)
            pData.append(float(a0.read()))
            pData.append(float(a1.read()))
            pData.append(float(a2.read()))
            pyplot.ylim([0, 1])
            del pData[0]
            l1.set_xdata([i for i in range(25)])
            l1.set_ydata(pData)  # update the data
            pyplot.draw()  # update the plot
            top.update()
        else:
            flag.set(True)
            break


# Associate port and board with pyFirmata
port = 'COM6'
board = pyfirmata.ArduinoMega(port)

# Using iterator thread to avoid buffer overflow
it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

# Assign a role and variable to analog pin 0
a0 = board.get_pin('d:7:i')
print(a0)
a1 = board.get_pin('d:6:i')
print(a1)
a2 = board.get_pin('d:5:i')
print(a2)
```

Comment: Врятли вы получите здесь ответ на свой вопрос. причина проста - вы для начала даже собрали схему не верно или нам тут описали неверно =) либо у вас 3 термопары, либо вы неверно ее подключили, ибо только с одной ноги из трех нужно снимать данные а остальные две к питанию(земля и плюс\опорка).

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ну, ошибки то точно нет, так как в используемой мной термопаре(MAX6675)  5 выходов, 2 из которых как раз питание, а 3 остальные являются интерфейсом для получения данных

Comment: "она подключается к трем цифровым выводам **(и двум выводам питания)** " Вот то что в скобках - не написано, а с тем уровнем вопросов что тут проскакивает - привык читать дословно =) собсно ваша ошибка в какой строке? и сей код же со стороны ПК а не ардуины работает если я правильно понял(мало ли, может уже есть среда для написания на питоне под ардуину)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да, прошу прощения,оплошность что не развернуто; насчет кода,да, это со стороны ПК,по своей сути он должен выводить сначала две кнопки (start, pause, exit), после нажатия на start он должен начать получать данные с ардуино с трех портов, к которым подключена термопара и в режиме реального времени строить график, обновляя данные в pData и удаляя оттуда старые, так вот, ругается он либо ошибкой, которая указана в шапке вопроса, либо такой `line 15, in onStartButtonPress
    pData.append(float(a0.read()))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков понимаю что в коде глупость, но где бы не искал, никак не могу найти нормальную информацию насчет считывания данных с 3 портов ардуино; при этом все рабочее, в плане ардуино и термопары, так как если писать простой код для вывода данных непосредственно в утилите arduino и выводить данные через встроенный монитор порта, то все выводит прекрасно

Comment: В питоне не силен, вторая ошибка возникает потому что не приходят данные. `a0.read()` - возвращает ноль данных.(null). Первая же говорит что производятся операции с данными имеющими либо разные типы либо операция с такими типами не поддерживается, может быть по той же причине - данные не пришли или пришли не в том формате. Я бы на вашем месте, пока ждете ответа от тех кто питон знает, заменил бы все a0\1\2.read() на "тестовые" данные (которые вы ожидаете получить) и проверил работу алгоритма.